# Xcode Source Editor Extension invoking existing menu item

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode-extension

The source editor extensions look good but it seems you can only manipulate the text in the source file and nothing else. Am I missing something or can you somehow invoke an existing editor menu command (such as code indent, show invisibles etc?). I'm looking for a way to fold / unfold code and use the existing refactoring menu commands in my extension but can't find any way to invoke them. I find it odd as one may create an extension that calls another (just as apps use other app extensions as editors / processors).

Comment: hey, did you ever find a solution to this elsewhere? I'm trying to do a similar thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72731712/trigger-keybind-or-invoke-menu-item-inside-xcode-extension-xcodekit

Comment: Did not find a way and gave up. Xcode extensions are currently pretty lame.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, unfortunate. I'll let you know if I find a miracle way somehow.